# How to manage logs of two seperate cron in a single project in java

Tags: spring, cron

There is an issue in running Multiple Cron in Spring. I have created multi module maven project in which there are two separate cron running but at some point of time they coincide and it becomes very tedious to debug from the log.

Is there any way of having a separate log or some way when one cron is running then another should not start, I mean at one point of time only one cron should run.

```
    @Scheduled(cron="0 0 */2 * * *")
        public void startAnalysis() {

            logger.info("Inside of Analysis scheduler");
            // Doing Something

        }

    @Scheduled(cron="0 0 */6 * * *")
        public void startAnalysis() {

            logger.info("Inside of Analysis1 scheduler");
            // Doing Something

        }
```

Above are the two crons that I am running. Currently, I am using sl4j for logging purpose.

Comment: are you running the two cron in a single thread or multi thread executor ?

Comment: currently using single thread

Comment: so as i described in my answer there wouldn't be  any overlapping and no more than one task could be executed simultaneously because one thread is available for their execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Spring by default uses a **single threaded Executor**. so no two
>   @Scheduled tasks will be execute simultaneously. even if there are two
>   @Scheduled methods in completely unrelated classes **will not overlap**
>   and that is because there is only a single thread to execute tasks.

the only possiblity for task to be executed at the same time is to have multi thread executors which defined as:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar 
     scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    }
}
```

- If you have such custom configuration that defines a thread pool for schedule tasks, you should **remove** it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two instances of the logger, each with a different name and configure them to log to different files in your logging framework.

Comment: Can I have any reference from where I can implement the two instances that you have mentioned

Comment: ```Logger LOG1 = LoggerFactory.getLogger("name1");
Logger LOG2 = LoggerFactory.getLogger("name2");``` Then configure them in the logging framework you use to log to different files, usually by configuring appenders.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Log4J programmatic config, you can separate different log file.

https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-configure-log4j-as-logging-mechanism-in-java?showall=&start=2#ProgrammaticConfiguration